# Isolating CSS animation from rest of page

Tags: css, animation, spinner

Got a css loading animation working, which I'm pleased about. Have a little bit of an issue with it, wondering if anyone knows the solution.

This is how the animation is working currently: http://www.wilsonschlamme.com/animation.html

I'd like to black out the entire content, and the second the animation has hit max size, the black screen goes away. So upon load the entire page would be black except the animation of course. And once the animation hits MAX size, all the content appears.

Any thoughts on this? Really appreciate anything. Having fun with this, just need to perfect a few things. Thanks.

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="animation.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"     
href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dorsa" <script     
type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script     
src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'>    
</script>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="270"/>
<!--time and date-->
<div id="timeandate">
<script>
function makeArray() {
 for (i = 0; i<makeArray.arguments.length; i++)
this[i + 1] = makeArray.arguments[i];
 }
 var months = new makeArray('January','February','March','April','May',
 'June','July','August','September','October','November','December');
 var date = new Date();
 var day = date.getDate();
 var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
 var yy = date.getYear();
 var year = (yy < 1000) ? yy + 1900 : yy;
 document.write(day + " " + months[month] + " " + year);
 window.onload = function () {
    DisplayCurrentTime();
  };
 function DisplayCurrentTime() {
    var date = new Date();
    var hours = date.getHours() > 12 ? date.getHours() - 12 :      
  date.getHours();
    var am_pm = date.getHours() >= 12 ? "PM" : "AM";
    hours = hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours;
    var minutes = date.getMinutes() < 10 ? "0" + date.getMinutes() :      
    date.getMinutes();
    var seconds = date.getSeconds() < 10 ? "0" + date.getSeconds() :     
  date.getSeconds();
    time = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " " + am_pm;
    var lblTime = document.getElementById("lblTime");
    lblTime.innerHTML = time;
  };
 <!--thisisanimation-->
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  function timer() {
  setTimeout(endAnim, 1000);  
   }
  timer();
  function restartAnim() {
 $('.loader-icon').removeClass('shrinking-cog').addClass('spinning-cog');
 $('.loader-background').addClass('color-flip'); 
 timer();
 $('.switches').show();
  }
 function endAnim() {
 $('.loader-icon').removeClass('spinning-cog').addClass('shrinking-cog');
  $('.loader-background').removeClass('color-flip'); 
 $('.again').delay(100).fadeIn('slow');
 $('.switches').fadeOut('slow');
 }
 $('.again').on('click', function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 restartAnim();
  });
  $('.switch').on('click', function(e) {
 var trigger = $(this);
 if ( !trigger.hasClass('active') ) {
  $('#loader').find('.loader-icon').addClass('hidden').filter('[data-cog*="'     
 +  trigger.data('trigger') + '"]').removeClass('hidden');
  trigger.addClass('active').siblings('.active').removeClass('active');
 }
 e.preventDefault();
 });
 });
</script>
 <div id="loader" class="overlay-loader">
    <div class="loader-background color-flip">
    </div>
    <img class="loader-icon spinning-cog" 
 src="http://pasqualevitiello.github.io/Tumblr-Style-Cog-
 Spinners/cogs/cog01.svg" data-cog="cog01">
    <img class="loader-icon spinning-cog hidden" 
src="http://pasqualevitiello.github.io/Tumblr-Style-Cog-
Spinners/cogs/cog02.svg" data-cog="cog02">
    <img class="loader-icon spinning-cog hidden" 
src="http://pasqualevitiello.github.io/Tumblr-Style-Cog-
Spinners/cogs/cog03.svg" data-cog="cog03">
    <img class="loader-icon spinning-cog hidden" 
src="http://pasqualevitiello.github.io/Tumblr-Style-Cog-
Spinners/cogs/cog04.svg" data-cog="cog04">
    <img class="loader-icon spinning-cog hidden" 
 src="http://pasqualevitiello.github.io/Tumblr-Style-Cog-
Spinners/cogs/cog05.svg" data-cog="cog05">
    <img class="loader-icon spinning-cog hidden" 
src="http://pasqualevitiello.github.io/Tumblr-Style-Cog-
Spinners/cogs/cog06.svg" data-cog="cog06">
    <img class="loader-icon spinning-cog hidden" 
src="http://pasqualevitiello.github.io/Tumblr-Style-Cog-
Spinners/cogs/cog07.svg" data-cog="cog07">
    <img class="loader-icon spinning-cog hidden" 
src="http://pasqualevitiello.github.io/Tumblr-Style-Cog-
Spinners/cogs/cog08.svg" data-cog="cog08">
    <img class="loader-icon spinning-cog hidden" 
src="http://pasqualevitiello.github.io/Tumblr-Style-Cog-
Spinners/cogs/cog09.svg" data-cog="cog09">
    <img class="loader-icon spinning-cog hidden" 
src="http://pasqualevitiello.github.io/Tumblr-Style-Cog-
Spinners/cogs/cog10.svg" data-cog="cog10">
    <img class="loader-icon spinning-cog hidden" 
src="http://pasqualevitiello.github.io/Tumblr-Style-Cog-
Spinners/cogs/cog11.svg" data-cog="cog11">
    <img class="loader-icon spinning-cog hidden" 
src="http://pasqualevitiello.github.io/Tumblr-Style-Cog-
Spinners/cogs/cog12.svg" data-cog="cog12">
    <img class="loader-icon spinning-cog hidden" 
src="http://pasqualevitiello.github.io/Tumblr-Style-Cog-
Spinners/cogs/cog13.svg" data-cog="cog13">
    <img class="loader-icon spinning-cog hidden" 
src="http://pasqualevitiello.github.io/Tumblr-Style-Cog-
Spinners/cogs/cog14.svg" data-cog="cog14">
    <img class="loader-icon spinning-cog hidden" 
src="http://pasqualevitiello.github.io/Tumblr-Style-Cog-
Spinners/cogs/cog15.svg" data-cog="cog15">
    <img class="loader-icon spinning-cog hidden" 
src="http://pasqualevitiello.github.io/Tumblr-Style-Cog-
Spinners/cogs/cog16.svg" data-cog="cog16">
    <img class="loader-icon spinning-cog hidden" 
src="http://pasqualevitiello.github.io/Tumblr-Style-Cog-
Spinners/cogs/cog17.svg" data-cog="cog17">
    <img class="loader-icon spinning-cog hidden" 
src="http://pasqualevitiello.github.io/Tumblr-Style-Cog-
Spinners/cogs/cog18.svg" data-cog="cog18">
    <img class="loader-icon spinning-cog hidden" 
src="http://pasqualevitiello.github.io/Tumblr-Style-Cog-
Spinners/cogs/cog19.svg" data-cog="cog19">
    <img class="loader-icon spinning-cog hidden" 
src="http://pasqualevitiello.github.io/Tumblr-Style-Cog-
Spinners/cogs/cog20.svg" data-cog="cog20">
    <img class="loader-icon spinning-cog hidden" 
src="http://pasqualevitiello.github.io/Tumblr-Style-Cog-
Spinners/cogs/cog21.svg" data-cog="cog21">
    <img class="loader-icon spinning-cog hidden" 
src="http://pasqualevitiello.github.io/Tumblr-Style-Cog-
Spinners/cogs/cog22.svg" data-cog="cog22">
    <img class="loader-icon spinning-cog hidden" 
src="http://pasqualevitiello.github.io/Tumblr-Style-Cog-
Spinners/cogs/cog23.svg" data-cog="cog23">
    <img class="loader-icon spinning-cog hidden" 
src="http://pasqualevitiello.github.io/Tumblr-Style-Cog-
Spinners/cogs/cog24.svg" data-cog="cog24">
</div>
<div class="spacer1">
</div>
<div class="spacer1">
</div>
<p>
     hi I should vanish and come back after animation!!!!
</p>
</html>
```

css

```
*{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;

}

body{
  text-align:center; /*For IE6 Shenanigans*/
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  font-weight: 900;
}

h1{
color: white;
overflow:hidden; /* older browsers */
}

.font1{
 font-family: 'Dorsa';
 letter-spacing: 1px;
top: 10px;
display:block;
position: absolute;
left: 5px;
width: 100%; /*makes the element 100%, to center it. */
}

img {
border-color: grey;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
}

#timeandate {
margin-top: 90px;
}

#timeandate2 {
position: relative;
margin-left: 5px;
}

#weather1 {
 position: absolute; /*makes it relative to the html element, (the first 
positioned element).*/
 width: 100%; /*makes the element 100%, to center it. */
top: 1700px;
right: -200px;
border-color: grey;
}

#weather2 {
 position: absolute; /*makes it relative to the html element, (the first 
positioned element).*/
 width: 100%; /*makes the element 100%, to center it. */
top: 1700px;
left: -150px;
border-color: grey;
border-weight: 2px;
}

#ShowText1{
position: relative;
overflow:hidden; /* older browsers */
 word-wrap: break-word;
padding-top: 100px;
max-width: 1000px;
font-size: 16px;
top: 250px;
line-height: 45px;
margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
}


.spacer1 {
margin-top:20px;
}

.overlay-loader .loader-icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
left: 43%;
z-index: 6;
  color: #42f498;
}

 .overlay-loader .loader-icon.spinning-cog {
 -webkit-animation: spinning-cog 1.3s infinite ease;
  -moz-animation: spinning-cog 1.3s infinite ease;
  -ms-animation: spinning-cog 1.3s infinite ease;
  -o-animation: spinning-cog 1.3s infinite ease;
  animation: spinning-cog 1.3s infinite ease;
background-color: #42f498;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spinning-cog {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(3)}
  20% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(3)}
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(3)}
}

@-moz-keyframes spinning-cog {
  0% { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(3)}
  20% { -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(3)}
  100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(3)}
}

@-o-keyframes spinning-cog {
  0% { -o-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(3)}
  20% { -o-transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(3)}
  100% { -o-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(3)}
}

@keyframes spinning-cog {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg) scale(3)}
  20% { transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(3)}
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg) scale(3)}
}

@-webkit-keyframes shrinking-cog {
  0% { -webkit-transform: scale(12) }
  20% { -webkit-transform: scale(12.2) }
  100% { -webkit-transform: scale(1) }
}

@-moz-keyframes shrinking-cog {
  0% { -moz-transform: scale(12) }
  20% { -moz-transform: scale(12.2) }
  100% { -moz-transform: scale(1) }
}

@-o-keyframes shrinking-cog {
  0% { -o-transform: scale(12) }
  20% { -o-transform: scale(12.2) }
  100% { -o-transform: scale(1) }
}

@keyframes shrinking-cog {
  0% { transform: scale(12) }
  20% { transform: scale(12.2) }
  100% { transform: scale(0) }
}

.overlay-loader .loader-icon.shrinking-cog {
  -webkit-animation: shrinking-cog .3s 1 ease forwards;
  -moz-animation: shrinking-cog .3s 1 ease forwards;
  -ms-animation: shrinking-cog .3s 1 ease forwards;
  -o-animation: shrinking-cog .3s 1 ease forwards;
  animation: shrinking-cog .3s 1 ease forwards;
background-color: #42f498;
}
```

Comment: For better answers, indent your code properly and try to provide a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another, more general answer.

If you want to initially hide multiple elements until animations is over, then show them, you can do the following:

- Give to each of those element a special class, say `appear-later`
- Define class `.appear-later { opacity: 0; }`
- With jQuery, after timer expires, remove that class from the elements who have it.

```js
setTimeout(function () {
    $('.appear-later').removeClass('appear-later');
}, 2000);
```

Also, it is better to put your javascript code after your html markup.

[Here's the pen](https://codepen.io/mikele/pen/yXgmGP)

I used `color: red` instead of `opacity: 0` in order to be more visible.

Also, in Codepen, you can load jQuery by going to Settings - Javascript - Quick-add

Comment: Hey that's a really creative solution! Nicely done! Thanks so much for your help sir.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](https://codepen.io/mikele/pen/rwjowp).

Initially I set body background to black.

```
body { background: black; }
```

After your timer, change it to transparent / white.

```
setTimeout(function () {document.body.style.background = "transparent";}, 2300);
```

(You can also do this by using CSS instead of js).

Comment: Hey that's awesome! Thanks @mikele. One thing, do you know how I set the background color to have a....higher z-index? There's an issue with if I have any font or, well anything, colored other than black, it still appears before the animation is over.

Comment: You can't do that. Please show me the jsfiddle or fork my codepen so I can try to fix it from there.

Comment: One solution is to give a class to those non-black elements, `.black {color: black!important;}` in it, then on `setTimeout()` above, add code to remove that class from all those elements. With jQuery, it would look like this: `setTimeout(function () {document.body.style.background = "transparent"; $('.black').removeClass('black'); }, 2300);`

Comment: thanks for your responses. Here's a codepen. Basically, I'm trying to make it so my background is always black, and the animation background is black as well. https://codepen.io/wilsons88/pen/EXZqZQ    Ideally no text is visible at all or anything until the animation is done loading.  Other thing that I'm noticing, far less priority, animation seems to be shifting my content upon loading. But one thing at a time. Thanks again Mikele! And sorry about including the javascript in the html, when I tried separating it it kept breaking my site! Your javascript is the first javascript entry however

Comment: I added another answer. Check it. Good luck.